# java jackson serialize json by methods

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I want my class to be automatically serialized by getter/setter methods instead of field declarations.

```
class SerializationTest{

 String notSerialized = "not serialized";

 public String getSerialized() {
    return "serialized";
 }
}
```

The `serialized` should be visible in the resulting json, while `notSerialized` should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@JsonAutoDetect` annotation to specify what gets serialized in a class. Like this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect( fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE, 
                 getterVisibility = Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY,
                 isGetterVisibility = Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY, 
                 setterVisibility = Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)

class SerializationTest{

 String notSerialized = "not serialized";

 String getSerialized() {
    return "serialized";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change visibility settings, or simply add an annotation to indicate that non-public field is to be detected:

```
@JsonProperty
String notSerialized = "not serialized";
```